# Heroku Potential security vulnerability in Ruby and YAML parsing command line check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, heroku, yaml

I received this Heroku vulnerability email:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/03/29/heap-overflow-in-yaml-uri-escape-parsing-cve-2014-2525/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuKjAZKXonjHpfsX%2B6u8vXaO%2FlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ASsNjI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFQrjAMapmyLgLUhE%3D

In the email, it says:

Check if you’re affected

Run the following on your app:

```
 $ heroku run “ruby -rpsych -e \”p Psych.libyaml_version.join(‘.’)\”” -a <app name>
```

If you see the following error message, then you are not vulnerable and can ignore the rest of this email:

```
  <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- psych (LoadError)
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, there was an error (using Mac):

```
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can I run the command line above correctly ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ heroku run “ruby -rpsych -e \”p Psych.libyaml_version.join(‘.’)\”” -a <app name>
```

has right and left hand quotes: `”` and `’`

Change these to straight quotes for starters: `"` and `'`

Comment: perfect. here is the command successfully executed: heroku run "ruby -rpsych -e \"p Psych.libyaml_version.join('.')\"" -a  <app name>

Comment: probably thankfully, i dont have the version less than 0.1.6: Running `ruby -rpsych -e "p Psych.libyaml_version.join('.')"` attached to terminal... up, run.2603
"0.1.6"

Comment: Yes, oddly enough, all of Heroku's instructions in that email are in right/left-hand quotes (not just the initial check). Make sure to change any that may pertain to you into straight quotes.